# I have 3 date range picker in my form I want to store 00-00-0000 00-00-0000

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, datepicker

when I am not selecting any of them it store by defult like this `1970-01-01 1970-01-01` and I want to store  `Zero(00-00-0000 00-00-0000)`

This is my date range insert code:

```
public function createBranch(){
        $bilty_date_range   =   $this->input->post('bilty_date_range');
        $temp = (isset($bilty_date_range) && !empty($bilty_date_range))
                ? $bilty_date_range : '00/00/0000 - 00/00/0000';
        $arr  = explode("-", $temp);
        $bilty_date_start = $arr[0];
        $bilty_date_end = $arr[1];

        $dispatch_date_range    =   $this->input->post('dispatch_date_range');
        $dis = (isset($dispatch_date_range) && !empty($dispatch_date_range)) 
               ? $dispatch_date_range : '00/00/0000 - 00/00/0000';
        $arrr = explode("-", $dis);
        $dispatch_date_start = $arrr[0];
        $dispatch_date_end = $arrr[1];


        $crossing_date_range    =   $this->input->post('crossing_date_range');
        $cro = (isset($crossing_date_range) && !empty($crossing_date_range)) 
                ? $crossing_date_range : '00/00/0000 - 00/00/0000';
        $arrrr = explode("-", $cro);
        $crossing_date_start = $arrrr[0];
        $crossing_date_end = $arrrr[1];

      }else{
    $data = array(
          'bilty_date_start'    => date('y-m-d',strtotime($arr[0])),
          'bilty_date_end'      => date('y-m-d',strtotime($arr[1])),
          'dispatch_date_start' => date('y-m-d',strtotime($arrr[0])),
          'dispatch_date_end'   => date('y-m- d',strtotime($arrr[1])),
          'crossing_date_start' => date('y-m-d',strtotime($arrrr[0])),
          'crossing_date_end'   => date('y-m-d',strtotime($arrrr[1])),
    );
```

script code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
//Initialize Select2 Elements
$('.select2').select2();
//Date range picker
$('#bilty_date_range').daterangepicker();
});
$(function () {
//Initialize Select2 Elements
$('.select2').select2();
 //Date range picker
 $('#dispatch_date_range').daterangepicker();

});
$(function () {
//Initialize Select2 Elements
 $('.select2').select2();
 //Date range picker
 $('#crossing_date_range').daterangepicker();

 });

 </script>
```

When I select date Range it Store selected date but when I am not selecting any date and submit form it store `1970-01-01 1970-01-01`

Comment: Just store null instead

Comment: i done that @Strawberry

Comment: Perfect. So problem solved

Comment: But still it store **1970-01-01 1970-01-01** @Strawberry

Comment: No. It doesn't. If you set it to store null then it will store null.